# Generate trajectories for 3 agents/robots with same tangent in specific point - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, simulink, robotics

I want to simulate the movements of 3 robots/agents in space and I would like to generate 3 different trajectories which have one constraint: in a certain time T the all the trajectories must have the same tangent.

I want something like in the following picture:
[image]

I need to do it through MATLAB and/or SIMULINK.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is enough for what I need or not but I probably figured out something.

What I did is to fit a polynomial to some points and constraining the derivative of the polynomial in a certain point to be equal to 0.

I used the following function:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54207-polyfix-x-y-n-xfix-yfix-xder-dydx-

It is pretty easy, but it saved me some work.

And, if you try the following:

```
% point you want your functions to pass
p1 = [1 1];
p2 = [1 3];
% First function
x1 = linspace(0,4);
y1 = linspace(0,4);  
p = polyfix(x1,y1,degreePoly,p1(1),p1(2),[1],[0]);
% p = [-0.0767    0.8290   -1.4277    1.6755];
figure
plot(x1,polyval(p,x1))
xlim([0 3])
ylim([0 3])
grid on
hold on

% Second function
x2 = linspace(0,4);  
y2 = linspace(0,4);  
p = polyfix(x2,y2,degreePoly,[1],[3],[1],[0])
% p = [0.4984   -2.7132    3.9312    1.2836];
plot(x2,polyval(p,x2))
xlim([0 3])
ylim([0 3])
grid on
```

If you don't have the polyfix function and you don't want to download it you can try the same code commenting the polyfix lines:

```
  p = polyfix(x1,y1,degreePoly,p1(1),p1(2),[1],[0]);
  p = polyfix(x2,y2,degreePoly,p2(1),p2(1),[1],[0]);
```

And uncommenting the lines:

```
  % p = [-0.0767    0.8290   -1.4277    1.6755];
  % p = [0.4984   -2.7132    3.9312    1.2836];
```

You will get this:

[image]

Now I will use this polynomial as a position (x,y) over time of my robots and I think I should be done. The x of the polynomial will be also the time, in this way I am sure that the robots will arrive in the 0-derivative point at the same time.

What do you think? Does it make sense?
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To have *tangents same all the time*, curves (*or trajectories*) **needs to** be **always parallel**. Generate trajectory for one object and keep other objects at fixed distance apart and following master trajectory.

In image provides if we take time next to three dots trajectories will not be same (*or parallel*) as objects moved in different directions. So i guess you've to keep then *always parallel*

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but I do NOT want tangents to be the same all the time. I want the tangent to be the same only at a specific point.

Comment: Ok, if your object position is updated at fixed intervals (*lets say steps*) and for ninety degree change in direction lets say slowest object requires (N) steps then at (t-N)th interval issue change directions command for slave objects. Because whatever is the time, key is to make path's parallel at that time.